# Get folder name from full file path c#

Tags: c#, directory-structure, subdirectory

I am trying to find out the full directory of folders. For e.g. Folder\TopLevel\Sub-Directory and onwards. However, the folders in Top Level are named all differently E.g. Top Level 1, Top level 2.. and they all have different sub directories etc. How can I show all directories at once even though all folders are named differently. Thanks!

My code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FolderStructure
{
public class Folder
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fileArray = Directory.GetDirectories("H:\\Folder\\TopLevel\\Sub-Directory\\");
        for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fileArray[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

[image: Results]

This image shows how it only goes until the sub folders. However, I want to know the things INSIDE the sub folders and onward.

Comment: you want to show all subdirectories of all TopLevel directories ?

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: have you tried to choose the entry point one level above `TopLevel` ? like : `Directory.GetDirectories("H:\\Folder", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a program I wrote a couple of weeks ago that saves results to xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```